# Unity material rendering using script working incorrectly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the hierarchy of Button component.

Button

- Image
- Text

The script used for rendering is as follows:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < idlist.Count; ii++){

                    GameObject addTypeButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton);
                    addTypeButton.transform.SetParent(ParentPanel, false);
                    var mybutton = addTypeButton.GetComponent<MyButton>();

                    //set text
                    mybutton.text.text = (string)sometext[ii];      

                    //get image
                    WWW www = new WWW((string)someImageUrl[ii]);
                    yield return www;

                    //set image
                    var b64_bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(www.text); 
                    Texture2D tex =  new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
                    tex.EncodeToPNG();
                    tex.LoadImage(b64_bytes); 
                    //yield return new WaitForSeconds (5) ;

                    mybutton.image.material.mainTexture = tex;

                    //testing
                    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../Saved["+ii +"].png", b64_bytes);
}
```

Testing command generates proper images in the sequence. 
However, in Unity the image is rendered on the next object.
[Here's the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJJ8H.png)

Where exactly I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don not use [`WWW.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-text.html) to load images. This is what [`WWW.bytes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-bytes.html) is there for. So, your `System.Convert.FromBase64String(www.text);` should be removed. You also don't need the `Texture2D.EncodeToPNG();` function here since the image you are downloading is already in *png* or *jpeg* format. Just save the downloaded image bytes directly.

Finally, if you want your saving stuff to work on every platform, you have to use `Application.persistentDataPath` instead of `Application.dataPath`. You should also use `Path.Combine` to concatenate paths instead of doing it manually.

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < idlist.Count; ii++)
{

    GameObject addTypeButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton);
    addTypeButton.transform.SetParent(ParentPanel, false);
    var mybutton = addTypeButton.GetComponent<MyButton>();

    //set text
    mybutton.text.text = (string)sometext[ii];

    //get image
    WWW www = new WWW((string)someImageUrl[ii]);
    yield return www;

    //set image
    byte[] downloadedImage = www.bytes;
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    tex.LoadImage(downloadedImage);
    //yield return new WaitForSeconds (5) ;

    mybutton.image.material.mainTexture = tex;

    //testing
    string savePath = Application.persistentDataPath;
    savePath = Path.Combine(savePath, "images");
    savePath = Path.Combine(savePath, ii.ToString());
    savePath = Path.Combine(savePath, ".png");

    File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, downloadedImage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
Well, the problem still exists.
The image is rendered on the next object, not the current one.
(As shown in screenshot in the question)

Comment: What is `idlist`?

Comment: Consider idlist.Count as number of elements.
It is just an array of data id.

Comment: Sorry. your question is incomplete. If you need help, you should edit your question and add more details. Include your `MyButton` script. Also, add how `idlist` is created.Post the urls used in the `someImageUrl` array.  Without these, I don't think that anyone can replicate your problem.